# Varied NPC AI in left 4 dead?

Tags: left-4-dead-2, left-4-dead

Do the different characters have different AI behaviors?

While playing left-4-dead with two of my friends we endless joke and complain about Coach's sniper shotgun.  He seems to last hit special infected from extreme distances with a *shotgun*.

Obviously, his super-human aim is attributed to the fact that he's a bot.  But what about his preference for a shotgun?  How about his bias towards killing special infected over common?
  Rochelle on the other hand seems to prefer to mow through common infected like a meat grinder with an automatic rifle.

Is this just me seeing a ghost in the machine or is there more to it?

Comment: Rochelle always shoots you in the back if you crouch between her and a target. Always. (Never had this problem with the other three AI. survivors.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Each of the AI bots (in L4D and L4D2) do have preferred weapon types that they will always try to use, depending on what types and level of weapon is available.

Shown here as `Level 1 Preference / Level 2 Preference`:

### L4D Survivors

#### In L4D

- **Bill:** Submachine Gun / Assault Rifle
- **Francis:** Pump Shotgun / Auto Shotgun
- **Louis:** Submachine Gun / Assault Rifle
- **Zoe:** Submachine Gun / Hunting Rifle

#### In L4D2

- **Bill:** Submachine Gun / Assault Rifle
- **Francis:** Pump Shotgun / Hunting Rifle
- **Louis:** Submachine Gun / Auto-Shotgun
- **Zoe:** Submachine Gun / Assault Rifle

### L4D2 Survivors

- **Coach:** All Shotgun variants (both weapon levels)
- **Ellis:** Submachine Gun / Hunting Rifle
- **Nick:** Submachine Gun / Assault Rifle
- **Rochelle:** Submachine Gun / Assault Rifle

**Source:** [L4D wikia](http://left4dead.wikia.com/wiki/The_Survivors)
*(specifically the character-specific "main article" pages linked from this source)*

Afraid I can't comment on if there are any preferences regarding selection of targets, or inhuman accuracy...