# Do the characters in Left 4 Dead have different attributes?

Tags: left-4-dead-2, left-4-dead

In Left 4 Dead, and also Left 4 Dead 2, does it make any difference which character you pick? Do they have different speed, toughness, accuracy, etc, or are they identical?

In single player, do they have different AI (weapon preferences, more likely to use or share healthpacks, etc)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only difference is in the bot AIs. [This Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10110/varied-npc-ai-in-left-4-dead) goes into depth on the specifics of that.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, all the characters have the same attributes except for the model used to represent them. This won't make much difference except in a versus game, and not much even then.

Answer (score 0):

In L4D1, Zoey has slightly better accuracy when it comes to pistols, Francis has less spread in shotguns, Bill has less spread in SMGs and ARs, and Louis gives a little more health with first aids and pills. It's not very noticeable if you don't look for it but it's there. I think Bill also gives the pipe bomb a little extra punch, and Francis gives the Molotov a little extra spread. Again not immediately noticeable but more zombies do die with Bill's pipe bombs, and the fire radius is a little bigger with Francis' Molotovs.

Answer (score -3):

Im pretty sure that there is no difference in between2 all the characters, if there was a difference the gane would be declared unfair and cheating of some kind, but i have noticed that in left 4 dead 2 there is a difference between running, rochelle does go a little faster than coach, probably due to coaches weight, now im pretty sure the game l4d and l4d 2 are quiet accurate besides the weight incident but that is all. This was reported or said by Raymond Sedillo (me) ;)